# Correct import of Firebase Storage in JavaScript Modules

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, import, firebase-storage

I got a Vue project where I want to use Firebase Storage. I already use Firebase Auth, Firestore and Analytics. That's how I import it:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    ... key etc. ...
})
const db = app.firestore()
const auth = app.auth()
const storage = app.storage()
```

Everything works but not storage. *"storage is not a function"*

If I do the following, everything works fine:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    ... key etc. ...
})
const db = app.firestore()
const auth = app.auth()
const storage = app.storage()
```

But regarding to Firebase, you should not do so as it imports all of Firebase *"You're using Firebase in development mode..."*

Actually, I copied my code from Firebase docs. So it should work. Maybe the problem is on another part of my project, but I really got no clue where to search as its many thousands lines of code.

How do I correctly import Firebase Storage with JavaScript Modules? Do I miss any Module?

Comment: How do you export them? Can you show the **entire** content of the file that contains `const app = firebase.initializeApp({... key etc. ...})`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import  storage from 'firebase';
```

and

```
export default {App, firebase};
```